# clear query string PostRequestHandlerExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, httpmodule

I need to clear the queryString so I implemented an httpmodule

```
 public void Init(HttpApplication context)
            {
             context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += newEventHandler(OnEndRequest);

    }
```

and this is the method :

```
 public void OnEndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;


            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
            { HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Clear(); }
    }
```

but it's giving an exception :

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Collection is read-only.
```

the purpuse is to hide the parameters shown in the adress bar , in order to make it impossible to the user to change the values of the parameters , I can't use post method , because , it's the problem of a whole application , so i can't go back to all pages and changes all the code .
to understand ; I want that the request MyPage.aspx?Param1=1 be processed and the response returned to the client but the addres bar must show MyPage.aspx instead of MyPage.aspx?Param1=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and simple way to get this feature ( clear the request parameters ) is 
using a client side method  :

this code will update the url shown in the adress bar without refreshing the page ( for browsers using html5 )

```
  var urlElts = document.documentURI.split('?');
                var newUrl = urlElts[0];
                window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", newUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

> the purpuse is to hide the parameters shown in the adress bar, in order to make it impossible to the user to change the values of the parameters

That's not how HTTP works. An HTTP application operates on a request sent by a client, so by definition, the client can see and alter all variables they want to send.

> I want that the request MyPage.aspx?Param1=1 be processed and the response returned to the client but the addres bar must show MyPage.aspx instead of MyPage.aspx?Param1=1

You cannot change the "address bar" (showing the current request URL) in any meaningful way during the current request. Even if you could, for example using JavaScript (causing the values to not be sent at all) or serverside by issuing a redirect (too late, the values have already been sent), this still misses the point: the user can see and alter everything they send.

If this `Param1=1` is actually a server-generated secret, then encrypt it. Alternatively, if it's a value they can change to the identifier of an object they don't have permissions to, then check the permissions serverside before processing the values.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to clear querystring is via response redirect such as

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, ""));
```

Comment: I'm getting  the following exception : An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String cannot be of zero length.

Comment: this is my code : HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query, "fddfd"));

Comment: where did the exception get thrown? at the line you posted?  your code seem okay

Comment: can you make sure your HttpContext.Current‌​.Request.Url.Query is not empty string.  If it is empty would cause that exception

Comment: it does redirect to the page , but data that populate the form is lost because I think the query parameter is cleared,

Comment: isn't that what you want? clear the query parameter.  If you need query string to populate data, then you can not use this method, as this will make another request without query string, hence two request all together.  One way to overcome is save your data to session, then redirect with query string clear (as method describe above) - then where page reach again, load the data from session instead of query string.

Comment: yes that's what I want , to load data using the query parameters , but to hide those parameters in the url showed in the adress bar . I can't use session attributes , because it's needed in the whole system , which is here already , so the changes I can do is generic , such this http module which will on the postprocessing phase clear the querystring .

Comment: If you want whole system why not put in HttpContext.Current.Application for storing the data?

Comment: The data varies depending on the request , every request has it's own parameters

Comment: I can't grasp what you really want to do - could you clear the question a bit with an example of why some of my suggestion would not work - because your original question was quite simple without mentioning all the data population problem.  If you needed the querstring data but simply don't want user to easily see it, then why not make it a post instead of get?